# iOS loading xib gives setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a BasicView:

```
#import "BasicView.h"

@implementation BasicView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

+(instancetype)initializeFromNib:(NSString*)nibName {
    return (BasicView*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:0] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

And a view inheriting from it:

```
@interface AlbumPicturesView : BasicView

/**
 The pictures label - need be removed once there are pictures in the album
 */
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *picturesLabel;

/**
 The pictures cell view
 */
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *picturesCollectionView;


@end

#import "AlbumPicturesView.h"

@implementation AlbumPicturesView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

with a xib file.

I try to show this view on screen with the following function:

```
/**
 Show the pictures view view on the right position on the screen
 */

    -(void) showPicturesView {
       _albumPicturesView = [AlbumPicturesView initializeFromNib:VIEW_ALBUM_PICTURES];
        [self.view addSubview:_albumPicturesView];
        float yPosition = _albumIconsView.frame.origin.y + _albumIconsView.frame.size.height;
        float height = self.view.frame.size.height - yPosition;
        _albumPicturesView.frame = CGRectMake(_albumPicturesView.frame.origin.x, yPosition, _albumPicturesView.frame.size.width, height);
    }
```

but i keep getting the:

```
[<AlbumPicturesView 0x113104> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key picturesCollectionView.
```

although it all set in the interface builder.. can someone please explain why?

Comment: That all looks quite reasonable.  Usually this error is a mismatch between the xib and the code, either because of the class name or the property name, but I don't see it here.  Have you tried cleaning the project and deleting derived data?

Comment: Actually deleting the derived data,cleaning are reconnection everything was quite helpful and worked... super weird :)

Comment: Probably you had an older version of some class built and cached and Xcode didn't detect that it should be rebuilt.  Happens.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an outlet in IB that you had connected to picturesCollectionView. Now that outlet does not exist in your class any more (or it's an incorrect class type). You need to remove it in IB as well.

Another possibility, you have selected `BasicView` as the class in xib instead of `AlbumPicturesView`.